# Avast Antivirus recognized python.exe as IDP.Alexa.51

Tags: python, virus

When i used Anaconda(I have installed Tensorflow), what can i do with it?
Can it be possible that one of the downloaded toolkit was infected?
I just redownload tensorflow and it never happened again.But suddenly i didnt write what module cause it.

Comment: What does VirusTotal say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First google search; [What Is IDP.ALEXA.51 and Should You Remove It](https://sensorstechforum.com/what-is-idp-alexa-51-and-should-you-remove-it/)

> IDP.ALEXA.51 is a detection primarily associated with online games
>   such as “SeaMonkey”, “Plants vs. Zombies” and others. The detected
>   object is reported to originate from .tmp and .exe files located in
>   various Windows folders, such as the %appdata% and %temp%. Despite the
>   false positive reports by researchers, it is usually detected by AVG
>   as malware and reported to be potentially hazardous for affected
>   computers.